# Build JSON Object from string containing multi-dimensional

Tags: javascript, json, multidimensional-array

I have an array of name/value objects (below).  The names are formatted to represent multi-dimensional array.

I need to build a full JavaScript object out of it(bottom).

```
[{
name: "getQuote[origin]",
value: "Omaha,NE"
}, 
{
name: "getQuote[destination]",
value: "10005"
}, 
{
name: "getQuote[country]",
value: "us"
}, 
{
name: "getQuote[vehicles][0][year]",
value: "1989"
},
{
name: "getQuote[vehicles][0][make]",
value: "Daihatsu"
}, 
{
name: "getQuote[vehicles][0][model]",
value: "Charade"
}, 
{
name: "getQuote[vehicles][0][count]",
value: "1"
}]
```

Into something like this:

```
{getQuote : 
  { origin : Omaha},
  { destination : 10005},
  {vehicles : [
   {
    year : 1989,
    make: Honda,
    model : accord
   },
   {
   //etc
}]
```

n

Comment: [There's no such thing as "JSON object".](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) You will most likely want just "object".

Comment: added clarification thank you, Oleg.

Comment: Well, it doesn't seems to be that hard to split it by [] blocks and auto-vivify objects on demand. The only tricky part would be is to vivify Array object for levels where only numeric indices are used.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov, that's what is the problem! _it doesn't seem to be that hard_, but try solving it, it will surely eat your brain up. I am trying to solve it since last 15+ minutes, not even close to the solution!

Comment: to break things up I am doing this: `strAry = myArray[i].replace(/\]/g, "").split("[");` But that is only part of the puzzle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it manually, like this:

```
var source = [ /* Your source array here */ ];
var dest = {};

for(var i = 0; i < source.length; i++)
{
    var value = source[i].value;

    var path = source[i].name.split(/[\[\]]+/);

    var curItem = dest;

    for(var j = 0; j < path.length - 2; j++)
    {
        if(!(path[j] in curItem))
        {
            curItem[path[j]] = {};
        }

        curItem = curItem[path[j]];
    }

    curItem[path[j]] = value;
}
```

`dest` is the resulting object.

Check it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/pnkDk/7/

Comment: sweet! short and really nice!

Comment: MMmm, some new things I haven't seen before thanks.  The solution I had wasn't nearly as elegant as this.  Gold Stars for you, Shedal.

Comment: This does not create Arrays for numerical indizes, as it should. I think you can easily fix that.